# ¿Cómo transformar un string en una lista de objetos?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Problema:**

Estoy parseando un *XML*, toda esa parte funciona a la perfección. Uno de los ítems es un string de nombres, separados por coma. Lo que quiero es un control que pueda *bindear* a una clase para armar y desarmar el string, según las selecciones del usuario.

**Pruebas**

La serialización y deserialización es automática y anda a la perfección, pero me deja obviamente el resultado en un string. La clase que serializa el *XML* tiene la interfaz `INotifyPropertyChanged`, funcionando para todas las propiedades.

Creo otra clase, que se supone que es la que voy a *bindear* a mi control:

```
public class ListaMarcas: System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool bMarcado;
    private string sTexto;
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((handler != null))
        {
            handler(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public bool Marcado
    {
        get
        {
            return bMarcado;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((bMarcado.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                bMarcado = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Marcado");
            }
        }
    }

    public string texto
    {
        get
        {
            return sTexto;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((sTexto.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                sTexto = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("texto");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Esta clase, debería llenar un objeto `ObservableCollection` para que funcione el ida y vuelta. Eso lo hago sobre la clase que serializa:

```
private ObservableCollection<ListaMarcas> pListaSistemas;

[XmlIgnore]
public ObservableCollection<ListaMarcas> ListaMarcas
{
    get
    {
        return pListaSistemas;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((pListaSistemas != null))
        {
            if ((pListaSistemas.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                pListaSistemas = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("select");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pListaSistemas = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("select");
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo hago para que la propiedad string que se llene sola, y sea transformada en una lista válida?

```
public consultaRestriccion restriccion
{
    get
    {
        return this.restriccionField;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this.restriccionField != null))
        {
            if ((restriccionField.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                this.restriccionField = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("restriccion");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.restriccionField = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("restriccion");
        }
    }
}
```

Tomar en cuenta que el código está escrito automáticamente desde *XSD2Code*, por lo cual está en una clase parcial.

El string viene con formato: `"dato1,dato2,dato3"`, con lo cual es fácil transformarlo en una lista haciendo `split`. ¿En qué parte debería poner ese `split` para que todos los objetos, se mantengan actualizados automáticamente?

### Edicion

La vista muestra ese string, como una lista de checkbox que el usuario puede seleccionar o no, y los seleccionados tienen que ser el string separado por comas que se vuelve a mandar al XML.

Comment: Lo que buscas es tener sincronizada la lista con el xml?

Comment: Exactamente. Pero en un modelo wpf, donde se haga en el vm y los cambios se reflejen solos.

Comment: Podrías utilizar una delegado que se ejecute junto con OnPropertyChanged o sobrescribir OnPropertyChanged para lograr lo que buscas

Comment: Onpropertychange es generico para muchas clases.. pero escucho ideas.

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034840/handling-onpropertychanged.
Si no te funciona, podrías intentar con delegados y eventos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871238/report-progress-backgroundworker-from-different-class-c-sharp aquí viene un ejemplo de cómo utilizar los delegados y eventos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para solucionar esto lo que hice fue crear un evento en la clase `ListaMarcas` que se ejecuta cada vez que cambia una marca.

```
...
public event Action CambioUnCheck;
...
public bool Marcado
{
    get
    {
        return bMarcado;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((bMarcado.Equals(value) != true))
        {
            bMarcado = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Marcado");
            CambioUnCheck?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

La llamada `CambioUnCheck?.Invoke();` es una simplificacion para verificar que `CambioUnCheck` no sea null antes de hacer el `invoke`.

El objeto `pListaSistemas` se mantiene igual, pero cuando lo lleno con los objetos del tipo `ListaMarcas`, tambien declaro una funcion que va a ser el receptor del evento:

```
public void HacerCambioDeCheck()
{
....
}
```

Y al llenar la lista hago algo asi:

```
ObjetoTemporal = new ListaMarcas { Chequeado = false, Texto = "1" };
ObjetoTemporal.CambioUnCheck += HacerCambioDeCheck;
ListaSistema.Add(ObjetoTemporal);
```

El unico problema, es que en la primer carga, el evento se ejecuta cada vez que voy cargando la lista por primera vez. Para evitar problemas con eso, agregue una variable en la clase:

```
private bool EvitarEvento = true;
```

y en el receptor del evento agregue:

```
public void HacerCambioDeCheck()
{
    if (EvitarEvento)
        return;
    ...
}
```

De esta forma, en la primera carga dejo EvitarEvento en true, y luego ya lo dejo en false asi el evento se ejecuta ante cada cambio.

La funcion `HacerCambioDeCheck` lo que hace es volver a cargar el string en el model, con cada cambio de un checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Podría ayudarte añadir un nuevo atributo en la clase ListaMarcas con un método que transforme el atributo string stexto en una lista.

```
private List<String> ldatos;

public List<String> lista
{
    get
    {
        return ldatos;
    }
    set
    {
        ldatos = split(stexto)
    }
}
```

Comment: Incluso podrías dentro del `split` decidir como se va a separar tu texto en objetos, por ejemplo:
"Esto, es tu ,string"

Si haces que el split se haga por "comas" entonces tendrás 3 objetos: 
[Esto] [es tu] [string]

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero esto justamente esta descripto en mi pregunta. El problema no es como hacer el split, si no como hacer que todas las clases queden sincronizadas mas alla del split. y como hacer el bind a los objetos de la vista.